# time not accepting arguments

Tags: arch-linux, time

I installed time but when I use it, I am getting the portable format, not the default format. When installed I think it said GNU time 1.7 or 1.72.

Commands like

```
time --help
time --version
```

fail with the error "command not found". The TIME environment variable is unset. Why is time behaving like this?

Comment: `time` is a shell keyword, you probably have to point to the full path of the installed time to use it:  `/usr/bin/time --version` or maybe alias it.

Comment: Is it possible you already have an alias for `time='time -p'` that would explain the portable format?

Comment: @Jesse_b no alias. I think it is using the bash keyword 'time' which apparently is identical to time -p

Comment: On my system the time builtin still has a `-p` option to print portable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Jesse_b is correct about how shells generally look up commands, there's an easier fix.

```
\time --version
```

Bash, ksh, zsh, and I believe a few other common shells will treat a leading backslash on a command with no path as 'skip to looking into the PATH for this thing.'

Also, knowing what the time builtin is, we could also get around this by running

```
time time --version
```

After all, the reason for the command not found error rather than a no such option error is because the shell builtin just runs the command that follows and checks how long it took to run when it finishes... which is the same thing that /bin/time does.

If you're expecting time to take arguments... are you wanting to find out what time it is?  Because that's the `date` command.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
\command builtin type time
```

to see which version of `time` you're running.

This is the paranoid version - usually just `type time` is sufficient, but the above will avoid situations where `alias type=echo`.

To see all binary versions of `time` in your `$PATH`, use `which -a time`.

Answer (score 3):

When looking for a command the shell uses the following preference:

1. aliases
2. Parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable
3. functions
4. BUILTIN commands
5. HASH table
6. Search `PATH`

So the `time` keyword will be used with preference over the installed version of `time` presumably found in your `PATH`.  You can overcome this with an alias, such as:

```
alias time=/usr/bin/time
```

(ensure the path is specific to whatever location you have installed time)